# Add filter problems

Tags: filters

I am confused about filters, why does this work:

```
function get_the_author_description2() {
    return 'test';
}
add_filter('get_the_author_description', 'get_the_author_description2');
```

but this one does not:

```
function get_the_author_firstname2() {
    return 'test';
}
add_filter('get_the_author_firstname', 'get_the_author_firstname2');
```

Confusing!

[I know these are depreciated functions, but the plugin I am trying to override is using them.]

Thanks

Comment: These filters do not exist..
You can check the full filters list in here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference  -  how about telling me what and where do you want to echo that 'test' ??

Comment: Thanks. I am using a child of the twentyeleven theme, which might be why the author description works.

What I am trying to do is hook into the "Just Another Author Widget" to display the post date in the widget.

Comment: Sorry man.. this plugin doesent work on my website at all (tried it) but i think if it works on your inatalltion you can just edit the plugin file and in any case dont understand what post?? this is supposed to show author details right? is is this on? --- > wordpress.org/extend/plugins/just-another-author-widget/

Comment: thanks for all your help. i want to avoid editing the plugin directly if I can, so that I can keep it up to date. If I want to hook into the functions that return author data, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the theme you're using has created custom functions that make your code above work. As Sagive SEO notes it doesn't appear to be a valid tag. You'll need to just commit to learning the code if you really want to understand how it works. If you don't actually take the time to explore the core code, you never actually get it.

Someone may answer a question for you here and there, but you won't really understand the way things work.

Try exploring the WordPress codex pages. Another good way to learn is to open the WordPress core code. The documentation is very extensive, and seems to improve with every version.

Here are a few valuable links to the_author tags that might shed some light:
[WordPress V3.0+Template Tag Reference Guide](http://www.dbswebsite.com/design/wordpress-reference/V3/author.php)

Check out the PHPXref WordPress docs. They should help you out quite a bit. If you hover over a function, tag etc... you'll notice a pop-up with some descriptive text.
[PHPXref WordPress docs](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html)